# Https required when login into keycloak

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

this question has been answered in several places but all solutions seem not to work for me.

envionment.
My keycloak is running docker
and I am using the EC2 amazon linux as the host.
When i deploy keycloak docker to ec2 i am able to run the first page of keycloak http://I{IP}:8181/auth
but when i try to login i get HTTPS required.

Solutions:
According to the info SO

- i should login into my container

$ docker run {containerName}

```
$ docker exec -it {containerName} bash

$ cd opt/jboss/keycloak/bin

$ ./add-user-keycloak.sh --server http://{IP}:8080/admin    
--realm master --user admin --password newpassword



NOW my problem is in the next command


$ ./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth 
--realm master --user admin
```

This returns HTTPS required as well same as when i try on the browser.

i also tried update REALM table from my database but it is read only even though its not a replica.
what else can i do for keycloak to woork while deployed in ec2